# Supermicro set boot order via bios config file

Tags: bios, supermicro

I've exported the bios config from one system via sum:

```
sum -i IP -u USER -p PASS -c GetCurrentBiosCfg > bios_config.xml
```

Now I want to apply this config to other machines of the same type:

```
sum -i IP -u USER -p PASS -c ChangeBiosCfg --reboot --file bios_config.xml
```

but I get errors about the hard drive selected (because the hard drive specified from the original system doesn't exist on the new system):

```
********************************<<<<<ERROR>>>>>*********************************

ExitCode                = 60
Description             = Invalid configuration file
Program Error Code      = 313.14
Error message:
        Invalid BIOS configuration file
        Unknown menu 'P0:Micron_5200_MTFDDAK480TDN' in BIOS configuration file
Instruction:
        If hardware resource has been changed, you may use --skip_unknown option
    to skip unknown forms

********************************************************************************
```

Even if I pass the `--skip_unknown` option I get undesirable results.

In the initial system I am setting boot option 1 to HDD and boot option 2 to PXE, everything else is disabled.  When I use the `--skip_unknown` option it sets boot option 1 to PXE and boot option 2 to HDD.

Here is a sample of what the bios config file has:

```
</Setting>
<Setting name="Legacy Boot Option #1" selectedOption="Hard Disk: Micron_5200_MTFDDAK480TDN" type="Option">
  <Information>
    <AvailableOptions>
      <Option value="0">Hard Disk: Micron_5200_MTFDDAK480TDN</Option>
      <Option value="1">CD/DVD</Option>
      <Option value="2">USB Hard Disk</Option>
      <Option value="3">USB CD/DVD</Option>
      <Option value="4">USB Key</Option>
      <Option value="5">USB Floppy</Option>
      <Option value="6">USB Lan</Option>
      <Option value="7">Network:FlexBoot v3.5.901 (PCI 01:00.0)</Option>
      <Option value="8">Disabled</Option>
    </AvailableOptions>
    <DefaultOption>Hard Disk: Micron_5200_MTFDDAK480TDN</DefaultOption>
    <Help><![CDATA[Sets the system boot order]]></Help>
    <WorkIf><![CDATA[  Boot mode select is not in 1 2 3 4 5   ]]></WorkIf>
  </Information>
</Setting>
```

---

Is there a way that I can modify this to just select whatever hard drive is available and not worry about the specific one?  Some sort of a wildcard perhaps?

Comment: If a wildcard for "whatever disk is first detected" really exists and is merely not visible to you right now, it might be displayed (or exported to a USB flash drive) when you boot the machine while fewer or no ATA drives are installed.

Comment: and `--skip_bbs` does nothing (sum 2.5.2)?

Comment: @JohannesM: No that has the same outcome as just --skip_unknown, it sets network first and HDD second even though HDD is first in the config file I'm importing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot I had asked this question but I did find a solution.  You can just abridge the string to remove the unique selections:

```
<Setting name="Legacy Boot Option #1" selectedOption="Hard Disk" type="Option">
```

Similarly for PXE you could just set:

```
<Setting name="Legacy Boot Option #1" selectedOption="Network" type="Option">
```